# What is the function of binding.invalidateAll( );?

Tags: android, android-databinding

pealse explain the function of `binding.invalidateAll();` in this chunk of code.

```
 binding.done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String hobbies=binding.enter.getText().toString();
            binding.gone.setText("Hobbies: "+hobbies);
            binding.gone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(hobbies.isEmpty()){
                binding.gone.setText("Enter Hobbies Above");
            }
            //Hide Keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            binding.invalidateAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats the part u do not understand from docs ? `Invalidates all binding expressions and requests a new rebind to refresh UI.`

Comment: I have remove the line and ran. There was no difference. so i want to know what does "Invalidates all binding expressions and requests a new rebind to refresh UI." mean? First i though it helps to refresh the page which is not so i am curious to know.

Answer (score 3):

What `binding.invalidateAll()` does is it recall all the stuff that's used for to refresh the UI . `Invalidate` word in general used for that purpose only in programming.

lets say you a variable `user` which you are using to set values to your UI elements. On first launch when binding expressions are evaluated the values will be set from the `user object` . Now if you made some changes to that object and you want to reflect those changes in UI you need to tell the binding that the data has been changed. Because `user` object in this example is not an Observable Object so binding will not know about changes.
That's when we call invalidate`.

Now in your case you are changing the UI by yourself i.e `setText`, `setVisibility()` etc, in code just above the `invalidate` this is why it does not affect anything.